# javafx.fxml.LoadException in Eclipse

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to implement a simple code using javafx and SceneBuilder that prints *click* when clicking on the Button. The program works well when I display only the screen, without interaction. But it gives the error below when I add it

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/home/nicolas/eclipse-workspace/ws-javafx/javafx1/bin/gui/view.fxml:7

    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2625)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(FXMLLoader.java:105)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:930)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:980)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:227)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:752)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2722)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2552)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2466)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3237)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3194)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3163)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3136)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3113)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3106)
    at javafx1/application.Main.start(Main.java:14)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$runLoop$11(GtkApplication.java:277)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: .viewController
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:928)
    ... 22 more
```

Main class:

```
package application;
    
import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
    public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        try {
        Parent parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/gui/view.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(parent);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    
}
```

FXML file (`view.fxml in gui package`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="400.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="gui.viewController">
   <children>
      <Button fx:id="btTest" layoutX="170.0" layoutY="208.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onBtTestAction" text="Button" />
      <Label layoutX="167.0" layoutY="126.0" text="Cick here!" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

ViewController class:

```
package gui;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

public class viewController {
    
    @FXML
    private Button btTest;
    
    @FXML
    public void onBtTestAction() {
        System.out.println("CLICK");
    }
    
}
```

I've tried to implement the solutions of the other posts, like changing details in the .fxml file, but I haven't been successful so far.

Comment: The class name for your controller class must follow standard Java naming conventions (it cannot begin with a lower case character)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error in this line :

> Parent parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/gui/view.fxml"));

make sure that '/gui/view.fxml' begin from the source package because relative path start from there .

Comment: I think it's right (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iW5D-rd419a6iQllHeFOqmdLX3VmmsMr/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: try put your fxml in the src/main/resources directory and then write directly `FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/view.fxml"));` withou /gui

Comment: This is clearly not the problem, since the stack trace indicates the line number in the FXML file where the error occurs.

Comment: It worked! I made this change:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iW5D-rd419a6iQllHeFOqmdLX3VmmsMr/view?usp=sharing 

I put the .fxml and the ViewController class in the same package as the Main. 

FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("view.fxml"));